# Duplicate workbook when saved into OneDrive sync folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am having this weird problem when saving my sheet into onedrive sync folder. Basically what i am doing with the below code is that I copy a sheet from my workbook then save it into a sync folder. When it does this, a saved copy with the filename that is stored in a specific cell  together with another copy with the same saved name with a 1 at the back of the file name will appear in the sync folder. When i step over to test the code, no such error occur. The error only occur if I run the macro. May i know why? Below is my code;

```
Sub SheetSplit1()
    '
    'Creates an individual workbook for each worksheet in the active workbook.
    '
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim sht As Object
    Dim strSavePath As String
    Dim sname As String
    Dim relativepath As String

    Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook

    'For Each sht In wbSource.Sheets

        Sheet10.Copy
        Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook

        sname = Sheet9.Range("I5") & "_" & _
        Format(Sheet9.Range("I8"), "ddmmmyyyy") & ".xlsx"
        relativepath = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & _
    "\SharePoint\Open Project Transition Check - Doc\Transition Dashboard Report\" & sname 'use path of wbSource

        'wbDest.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Clear 'clear filename from new workbook cell A1

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relativepath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, _
        CreateBackup:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True


        wbDest.Close False 'close the newly saved workbook without saving (we already saved)

    'Next

    MsgBox "DashBoard Report Saved!"

End Sub
```

Greatly appreciate anyone who could assist me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could give a definitive answer, or Microsoft would contribute.
I have similar connected problems. It seems that another version of the file may be or "appear to be" open elsewhere, thus preventing excel/Onedrive from completing the save action. 
Rather than overwrite it(lets face t, that was the command) it creates a "version" filename(1).
I am guessing this is the same as when you do it manually and you are asked to resolve a conflict.
So far I have failed to find out how you can discover and solve the problem in code.
I solved it in one instance by mapping a drive on the offending desktop and first closing any open versions before save, but that is not a robust long term solution.

Test this by setting  Application.DisplayAlerts = True and capturing errors.
"On error got catch"   after the last dimension line then
"exit function
catch:
msgbox err.description"
before "end  sub"